# Is there an XPATH function or operator to compare the depth of nodes?

Tags: xpath, xslt-2.0

Example:

```
<ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <ul>
        <li>item 2</li>
        <li>item 3</li>
        <ul>
            <li>item 5</li> <!-- context node -->
        </ul>
    </ul>
    <li>item 6</li>
</ul>
```

If the `li` element with the text `item 5` is the context node, the expression `following::*` would yield the `li` element with text `item 6`.  Is there a built-in way to get the difference in depth of these nodes? i.e if we defined the root `ul` as having depth 0, then it's children (`li` item 1, `ul`, `li` item 6) would have depth 1, and so on.  `li` item 5 has depth 3.

The `ancestor` axis could be used from both nodes, but wonder if there is another way.  Another possibility might be to keep state information when traversing the tree and if the parent had following siblings?

Comment: What is not working with using the  (count of the?)`ancestor` axis? As for keeping state information when traversing the tree, in XSLT 3 you might be able to do that with accumulators.

Comment: @MartinHonnen the `ancestor` axis would work, I was curious if there is a more elegant solution. The accumulator is a nice feature for XSLT 3.

Answer (score 1):

The question is tagged as XSLT 2 but as you mentioned tree traversal to keep state information it might be worth mentioning an XSLT 3 accumulator e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">
    
  <xsl:mode use-accumulators="depth"/>
    
  <xsl:accumulator name="depth" as="xs:integer" initial-value="0">
      <xsl:accumulator-rule match="/" select="0"/>
      <xsl:accumulator-rule match="*" select="$value + 1"/>
      <xsl:accumulator-rule match="*" phase="end" select="$value - 1"/>
  </xsl:accumulator>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="*">
      <xsl:comment select="accumulator-before('depth'), count(ancestor-or-self::*)"/>
      <xsl:next-match/>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ei5R4uS

I know you have defined the value for the root element as 0 but using 0 for the root node `/` and then `+1` as the depth for its child elements seems more reasonable to me.